# Mini-Architecture Strategy for My App

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I wanted to ask for some help in tackling a specific goal I need to solve in my Swift code, and was hoping someone could give some advice for a strategy.

Without jumping fully into details, the situation is I have two view controllers where you can select a date. On one view controller, it displays a week for that date. So if I pick tomorrow, it will show me the days in this week. The other view controller also allows you to pick a date, however that will display the current month you are in. The actual date picker is reused by the way.

My initial thought is, for week, "Just take the date you pick, and use ns date components and figure out what the start/end date are". This is code that would happen in the view controller and is obviously very specific to the week view controller.

For the month, then, my thought for a quick and dirty way is to just have different code that simply analyzes the month of the selection you made, and viola` you have your month.

This just does not ring out as elegant for me. Maybe i'm just tired but I can't think of a better strategy, for example a more abstract or service-oriented way of determining some block of time surrounding a particular date, where that block of time is germane to the controller.

What are some better ways I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you are describing.  You could create a utility class that implements `+ (NSDate *)weekForDate:(NSDate *)` and `+ (NSDate *)monthForDate:(NSDate *)` but that would just be moving the code from the view controller to another class

Answer (score 0):

I decided this was a nice way to solve it (Paulw11 was spot on about having a utility class too)

Given that the user can pick a date (one day) but different view controllers will need a diff. period of time surrounding chosen date, I can have a function that will take in a given date (chosenDate) and the second parameter is an enumeration for week/month. Later if this ever expands (perhaps I want annual, or bi-monthly, or custom things) I can handle the functionality for that within the function.

Of course, if things ever got out of hand I could just override the function to pass in any start/end date range you want, but for the commonly used ones (i'll likely only ever use week, month, and probably year) this will work.